# Prototype event not triggered inside another function ($.proxy)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to fix a plugin that I found for a Time Picker, it's the following one:

https://github.com/grimmlink/TimingField

It works almost as expected with exception of one crucial line:

```
this.tpl.find('.timingfield_hours .timingfield_next')
    .on('mouseup', function() {
        clearInterval(timeoutId);
        return false;
    })
    .on('mousedown', function(e) {
        timeoutId = setInterval($.proxy(this.upHour, this), 100);
        return false;
    });
```

This section of the code in my understanding is for triggering the method of upHour every 100 ms after the user press the button (the same code could be replicated for minutes or seconds). However, it's not triggered at all, but if you remove the section of the interval and just called like this:

```
this.tpl.find('.timingfield_hours .timingfield_next')
    .on('mousedown', $.proxy(this.upHour, this));
```

It works as expected, but you must do click by click each time in order to make it work.

Something that I'm sure is that the setInterval is being triggered because I modified it as this:

```
this.tpl.find('.timingfield_hours .timingfield_next')
    .on('mouseup', function() {
        clearInterval(timeoutId);
        return false;
    })
    .on('mousedown', function(e) {
        timeoutId = setInterval(function(){
            console.log('x');
            $.proxy(this.upHour, this)
        }, 100);
        return false;
    });
```

I'm aware that the timeoutId is moving, but the field is not changing at all. This is a fiddle with the code:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/xeapwbxc

The location of the issue is in the line 32 of the JS. Does anybody know what should I change in order to make it work? Or why the function is not being called from the internal function? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `this.upHour` in the `init` function itself. Inside mousedown handler `this` will be a button not a plugin instance. [Working example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/dyge7wv9/)

```
var upHour = $.proxy(this.upHour, this); // `this` is plugin instace 
this.tpl.find('.timingfield_hours .timingfield_next')
            .on('mouseup touchstart', function() { clearInterval(timeoutId); return false; })
            .on('mousedown touchend', function(e) {
               console.log(this); // `this` is button element
               timeoutId = setInterval(upHour, 100); return false;
             });
```

As of your approach

```
timeoutId = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('x');

        // this only creates new function and never call it
        // also `this` will be global or undefined (in strict mode) 
        $.proxy(this.upHour, this)
    }, 100);
```

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete Glad I could help.